# Can't download or update Mac App Store apps

Tags: mac-appstore, upgrade

I can't seem to download or update any apps purchased in the Mac App Store.  So far I've tried most of the usual troubleshooting tips found by googling the issue (deleting caches & preferences, signing out & back in, rebooting).  Nothing's helped at this point.  I've deleted the app from the Applications folder to try to re-install it but when I click Install, the wheel on the top left just spins for a few seconds then nothing happens & the install button reappears.  I don't have any problems on a different Mac.  I do have the same issue if I create another account on this Mac, so it must be a system setting somewhere...

Comment: Have you some network security app installed like LittleSnitch ?

Comment: No, nothing like that.  Nothing's changed on this Mac security wise since the last time I successfully used the Mac App Store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why this worked, but I just downloaded the apps through the app store on a different Mac, then copied them over to the problematic Mac.  Since then, there have been other updates applied with no problem.  I'm not sure what the problem here was.